# Minimum observance for Aliyah/leading prayer

Tags: halacha, halacha-theory, torah-service, chazzan-prayer-leader, orach-chaim

I’m curious, according to Halacha, what is the minimum level of observance to be called to the Torah of act as shaliach Tzibbur. Relevant questions about specific Issurim have been asked here before, but my question is on a broader level what criteria poskim use to decide what violations (without stopping and repenting) disqualifies one from these.

Comment: partly relevant: [Are there any restrictions about a chazzan if there are questions about his orthodoxy?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14256/11501)

Comment: @mbloch looks like a dup to me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which to choose: relations with a non Jewish woman or wasting seed](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/71266/which-to-choose-relations-with-a-non-jewish-woman-or-wasting-seed)